# Bitmask type to perform binary operations

Tags: c#, bitwise, enum

Without any specific implementation details, how would you create a bitmask *type* that wraps binary arithmetic into something easy to read? Ideally, this would be used with an `enum`, which is why there are some generic methods.

**Some Questions**

1. Is the *type* a struct or class?
2. Is the *type* generic or are certain methods generic?
3. Is it okay to constrain the generics to `struct, IConvertible`?
4. Is a *type* like this preferred when working with bitmasks?

**Starting Example:** [Here's a fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/os3qlV)

```
//Example Use
var days = new Bitmask((ulong)(Day.Monday | Day.Tuesday));
days.Contains((ulong)Day.Friday); //false
days.Contains((ulong)Day.Monday); //true
//Example Use END    

public enum Day { Monday = 1, Tuesday = 2, Wednesday = 4, Thursday = 8, Friday = 16, Saturday = 32, Sunday = 64 }

public struct Bitmask
{
    //Bitmask Value
    private ulong _value;
    public ulong Value 
    { 
        get { return _value; }
        set { _value = value; }
    }   

    //Constructor
    public Bitmask(ulong value) { _value = value; }


    //Methods
    public bool Any() { return _value != 0; }

    public void Clear() { _value = 0; }

    public bool Contains(ulong value) { return (_value & value) == value; } 

    public bool Equals(ulong value) { return _value == value; }

    public List<TEnum> ToList<TEnum>() where TEnum : struct, IConvertible
    {
        var local = this;
        var result = ((TEnum[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum))).Where(m => local.Contains<TEnum>(m)).ToList();
        return result;  
    }   
}
```

Comment: The implementation of `Contains` doesn't look right to me: `new Bitmask(1).Contains(3)` returns `true`.

Comment: @mjolka Actually, `new Bitmask(1).Contains(3)` doesn't really make sense so I will add some code to clarify what the type is doing. Also, the fiddle provides some extra details.

Comment: Enum provides the method HasFlag, much like your 'Contains'.

Comment: Don't add extra code as it invalidates answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you are misusing an `enum` as just a more cumbersome way to write a `ulong`.

If the days of the week are meant to be treated as a set rather than a single value (i.e., more like checkboxes than radio buttons), then you should be using the `[Flags]` attribute.  In fact, this is almost exactly the [example given in the MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx):

> ```
> [Flags]
> enum Days2
> {
>     None = 0x0,
>     Sunday = 0x1,
>     Monday = 0x2,
>     Tuesday = 0x4,
>     Wednesday = 0x8,
>     Thursday = 0x10,
>     Friday = 0x20,
>     Saturday = 0x40
> }
>
> class MyClass
> {
>     Days2 meetingDays = Days2.Tuesday | Days2.Thursday;
> }
> ```

Personally, I'd write the constants using left-shift operators:

```
[Flags]
enum Days2
{
    None = 0,
    Sunday = 1 << 0,
    Monday = 1 << 1,
    Tuesday = 1 << 2,
    Wednesday = 1 << 3,
    Thursday = 1 << 4,
    Friday = 1 << 5,
    Saturday = 1 << 6
}
```